# Dart Spectre Model can not be rendered

Tags: dart

There was a problem running the Spectre "depth_texture_main.dart" example in Dart version 26274.

I ran the code unmodified from https://github.com/johnmccutchan/spectre.

Chromium message:
The page at 127.0.0.1:3030 says:
Could not run DepthTexture: Illegal argument(s):
Model cannot be rendered. See console.

Console message:
...
Could not run DepthTexture: Illegal argument(s): Model cannot be rendered.

## 0      Model.Model (package:spectre/src/spectre_example_ui/model.dart:35:7)

...